# Google - Compute Engine VM - cannot bind to internal IP

Tags: interface, binding, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

We have created 2 x VMs (both with the same spec - Windows 2012 R2, 2 x cores, 12Gb, 1 static IP).
I have deployed our tomcat application to one server and the app responds on both localhost and the internal ip address of the VM e.g.
http://localhost:90/integrationmanager
http://10.150.4.11:90/integrationmanager
So that all works normally on that server.

On the the second server, the app responds ok on localhost but it does not respond on the internal IP address of 10.150.4.8
http://localhost:90/integrationmanager
but this fails http://10.150.4.8:90/integrationmanager

The tomcat server.xml is the same for both servers so it is not an app config issue. since the test is being done direct on the local server it is not a VPC firewall issue as the request is not going off-box.

I have switched back to an ephemeral address from a static and that made no difference. 
Windows Firewall is disabled on both private and public networks, it is not a member of a domain so that is not applicable.

Any ideas ? I am considering blowing away the VM and starting again

Answer (score 1):

it turns out that McAfeee (which has its own firewall) had been installed on the server which had the issue. Now disabled and all is working ok.